# Need complete implemention of idempotent repository in Camel File2 component?

Tags: apache-camel, hazelcast

> I am using camel over a clustered environment and want to use a
>   readlock on my file consumer endpoint. The only cluster safe readlock
>   is the idempotent readlock however this requires an
>   idempotentRepository to be set on the file uri.
>
> I need complete implemention of idempotentRepository in clustered
>   environment.

*My current implementation is as below, It is throwing error for implementation of idempotentRepository*

```
  <route id="request" >
                <from uri="file:someFolderLocation?readLock=idempotent&amp;readLockRemoveOnCommit=true"/>
               <to uri="file: someOtherFolderLocation "/>
```

I am newbie in camel. Please advice.

Comment: If you're just asking for code, this question is offtopic. Requesting code be written for you, or asking for offsite resources is off topic.